# What is the four-dimensional representation of the $SU(2)$ generators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, group-representations, lie-algebra

Recently, I have been learning about non-Abelian gauge field theory by myself. Thanks @ACuriousMind very much, as with his help, I have made some progress.

I am trying to extend the Dirac field equation with a coupling to a $SU(2)$ gauge field:
$$(i{\gamma}^{\mu }{D}_{\mu}-m)\psi =0$$ 
where
$${ D }_{ \mu  }=\partial _{ \mu  }+ig{ A }_{ a }^{ \mu  }{ T }_{ a }$$
the ${ T }_{ a }$ is the $SU(2)$ Lie group generator, with $[{ T }_{ a },{ T }_{ b }]=i{ f }^{ abc }{ T }_{ c }$, and the ${\gamma}^{\mu }$ are the Dirac matrices. When I write explicitly the first part of the Dirac equation, with spinor form $\psi=(\phi,\chi)^T$, I get (spatial part):
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & { \sigma  }^{ i } \\ -{ \sigma  }^{ i } & 0 \end{pmatrix}\partial _{ i }\begin{pmatrix} \begin{matrix} \phi  \\ \chi  \end{matrix} \end{pmatrix}+ig\begin{pmatrix} 0 & { \sigma  }^{ i } \\ -{ \sigma  }^{ i } & 0 \end{pmatrix}{ A }_{ a }^{ i }{ T }_{ a }\begin{pmatrix} \begin{matrix} \phi  \\ \chi  \end{matrix} \end{pmatrix}$$
**My problem is: I only known the linear representation of ${ T }_{ a }$ is Pauli spin matrix from text book, but they are the set of 2-dimension matrixes, In above expression, I need to know the 4-dimension matrix of ${ T }_{ a }$ because of the spinor is 4-dimension, I
check some test book, but didn't find the explicitly statement of the 4-D matrix.**

So, as mentioned in title, **What is the 4-dimension representation of the $SU(2)$ generators, or how can I calculate it?**

Comment: it is a combination of (usual) 2-dim pauli matrices (in some representations)

Comment: Tanks! but can you describe the combination procedure more explicit? I not very familiar with the Lie group theory,please.

Comment: take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices, https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/pauli-matrices-as-generators-of-su-2.359317/, effectively pauli matrices **are** the generators of $SU(2)$

Comment: see these notes on unitary groups and representations http://www.cmth.ph.ic.ac.uk/people/d.vvedensky/groups/Chapter9.pdf as well

Comment: Can you tell me explicitly, when I do the calculation in above, Which matrix representation I can use, dose it the original 2*2 Puali matrix $\sigma_{i}$?

Comment: Yes you can use the pauli-matrices. Note that there are combinations of pauli matrices which are also generators (much like a vector basis can have other combinations of vectors which are also a basis)

Comment: but in mathematics, how can do a matrix product with a 4*4 ($\gamma^{\mu}$) matrix and a 2*2 matrix($\sigma_{i}$)? or, I can seem the off-dig terms in $\gamma^{\mu}$ as a number, and take matrix product with $\sigma_{i}$?

Comment: you have the matrices inside other matrices (a tensor product) in your question, as such the final dimension is 4

Comment: em, let me ask directly: when I take the matrix produt of $\gamma^{\mu}\sigma_{i}$, Dose it equal to (for instant $\sigma_{x}$):$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & { \sigma  }^{ i } \\ -{ \sigma  }^{ i } & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} { \sigma  }^{ i } & 0 \\ 0 & -{ \sigma  }^{ i } \end{pmatrix}$$>? If it is't right, which is right?

Comment: see these [notes on non-abelian gauge theories](http://cds.cern.ch/record/292286/files/B00008237.pdf), the dimensions of the lie group (the parameters) need not be the same as the space-time dimensions, furthermore the pauli matrices are effectively the (infinitesimal) generators of $SU(2)$

Comment: en, Thanks your effort to help,thanks, by reading the note page 33, I fund the express in Eq.9.15: $\frac { 1 }{ 2 } i{ W }_{ \mu  }^{ a }\overset { - }{ \psi  } { \gamma  }^{ \mu  }{ t }_{ a }\psi $, how to deal this term in the follow calculation.Especially,the current of fermion in Eq.10.13:$\overset { - }{ \psi  } { \gamma  }^{ \mu  }{ t }_{ a }\psi$ .How to write it in a complete matrix form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comment to the question (v4): OP seems to effectively conflate spacetime symmetries and internal gauge symmetries. They act in different representations, or more precisely as a [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) of representations.

For instance the fermion $\psi$ carries two types of indices, say $\psi^{\alpha i}$, $\alpha=1,2,3,4,$ and $i=1,2$. The fermion acts

1. as a $4$-dimensional Dirac spinor representation under Lorentz transformations.
2. as a $2$-dimensional fundamental representation of the gauge group $SU(2)$ under gauge transformations.

Similarly, the $4\times 4$ Dirac matrices $\gamma^{\mu}$ and the $2\times 2$ $SU(2)$ gauge group generator $T^a$ act on different representations. The product of $\gamma^{\mu}$ and $T^a$ is a tensor product. In particular, the term $\gamma^{\mu}T^a\psi$ in OP's formula again carries two types of indices, and is evaluated as

$$ (\gamma^{\mu}T^a\psi)^{\alpha i}~=~(\gamma^{\mu})^{\alpha}{}_{\beta}~ (T^a)^{i}{}_{j}~\psi^{\beta j}. $$

Comment: em, Dose you mean,**because the SU(2) symmetry is internal (not involve space-time), the representation of the SU(2) generator always 2*2 puali matrix when the Covariant derivative asct on the 4*1 spinor (for SU(2), it is 2*1)**?please continuely focus on this post, thanks!

Comment: Great!!thanks your powerful help!I think I understand what you means. I write it down, please check it, if it incorrect, please point out, if it is correct, also please tell me,thanks!

Comment: Great!thanks your powerful help!I think I understood. I write it down, please check it, if it incorrect,please point out,if it is correct, also please tell me,thanks!**As your mean,the Dirac field $\psi$ is a tensor product of it's space-time part and internal part as $\psi ={\psi}^{\alpha}\bigotimes {\psi}_{i}$, So  the expression ${\gamma}^{\mu}{T}^{a}\psi =({\gamma}^{\mu}{ \bigotimes T }^{a})({\psi}^{\alpha}\bigotimes {\psi}_{i})=({\gamma}^{\mu}{\psi}^{\alpha})\bigotimes {(T}^{a}{\psi}_{i})$, result is a 8*1 column vector,and every element is ${({\gamma}^{\mu}{T}^{a}\psi)}^{\alpha i}$**